# Savebox inside \newcommand vs \newenvironment

Tags: environments, boxes

I have created a way to save answers to the exercises and generate them automatically later. Still, savebox doesn't seem to work inside an environment, while working fine inside a command. I'm working on environment `odpowiedz` and command `modpowiedz` in this example. The first one doesn't want to save the box, but the second one works just fine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fontsize=14pt]{fontsize}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,mathtools,bm,amsthm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,polish]{babel} 
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx,float}
\usepackage{xargs}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand\namedbox[2]{%
    \ifcsname#1\endcsname\else%
        \expandafter\newsavebox\csname#1\endcsname%
    \fi%
    \expandafter\sbox\csname#1\endcsname{#2}}
\newcommand\usenamedbox[1]{\expandafter\usebox\csname#1\endcsname}

\newcounter{R}[section]
\numberwithin{R}{section}
\newcounter{P}[section]
\numberwithin{P}{section}
\newcounter{S}[section]
\numberwithin{S}{section}
\newcounter{M}[section]
\numberwithin{M}{section}
\newcounter{D}[section]
\numberwithin{D}{section}
\newcounter{odp}
\newcounter{sposob}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\newcommand{\link}[1]{\textbf{\hyperref[#1]{#1}}}

\newcounter{mylabelcounter}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\labelodp}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{mylabelcounter}%
    \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\newlabel{#1}{{1}{\thepage}{{\unexpanded{#1}}}{mylabelcounter.\number\value{mylabelcounter}}{}}}}
\makeatother

\newenvironmentx{zadanie}[3][2,3]{
        \refstepcounter{#1}%
        \gdef\kod{#1.\csname the#1\endcsname}\par%
        \minipage[t]{\textwidth}%
            \label{\kod}\ignorespaces\textbf{\hyperref[O.\kod]{\kod}}\if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\else(#2)\fi\if\relax\detokenize{#3}\relax\else(#3p.)\newline\fi}
    {\endminipage\vspace{1ex}\par}
    
\NewEnviron{odpowiedz}[1][nod]{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{d}}{%
        \link{\kod}~\minipage[t]{0.9\textwidth}%
            \raggedright\setcounter{odp}{0}\setcounter{sposob}{0}%
            \BODY%
        \vspace{1ex}\endminipage\\}{}%
    \namedbox{\kod}{%
        \minipage[t]{0.9\textwidth}%
            \raggedright\setcounter{odp}{0}\setcounter{sposob}{0}%
            \BODY%
    \vspace{1ex}\endminipage}}
    
\newcommand{\modpowiedz}[1]{\namedbox{\kod}{#1\hspace{1.8em}}}

\newcommand{\wstawodpowiedz}[1]{\leavevmode\labelodp{O.#1}\link{#1}~\usenamedbox{#1}\penalty0}
\newcommand{\odpowiedzi}[1]{\foreach \n in {1,...,\arabic{#1}}{\wstawodpowiedz{#1.\thesection.\n}}}



\begin{document}
\section{Exercises}

\begin{zadanie}{D}
    Solve equation $x+1=2$.
\end{zadanie}
\begin{odpowiedz}
    $x=1$
\end{odpowiedz}

\begin{zadanie}{D}
    Solve equation $x+1=3$.
\end{zadanie}
\modpowiedz{$x=2$}

\subsection{Answers}
\odpowiedzi{D}
\end{document}
```

In this example answer `D.1.1` is created by `odpowiedz` and answer `D.1.2` by `modpowiedz`.
[image]

Comment: an enviroment is a group so any local assignments are restored at the end of the  group

Comment: Remark, you can keep this question around, I think it's useful signpost.

Comment: What do you mean by signpost?